# How to train tfidfvectorizer for new dataset

Tags: text-classification

I am doing document classification using tfidfvectorizer and LinearSVC. I need to train tfidfvectorizer again and again as new dataset comes. Is there any way to store current tfidfvectorizer and mix new features when new dataset comes.

Code :

```
if os.path.exists("trans.pkl"):
    with open("trans.pkl", "rb") as fid:  
        transformer = cPickle.load(fid)
else:
    transformer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,stop_words = 'english')
    with open("trans.pkl", "wb") as fid:
       cPickle.dump(transformer, fid)
X_train = transformer.fit_transform(train_data)
X_test = transformer.transform(test_data)
print X_train.shape[1]

if os.path.exists("store_model.pkl"):
    print "model exists"
    with open("store_model.pkl","rb") as fid:
        classifier = cPickle.load(fid)
    print classifier
else:
    print "model created"
    classifier = LinearSVC().fit(X_train, train_target)
    with open("store_model.pkl","wb") as fid:
        cPickle.dump(classifier,fid)
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

I have 2 diff train files and 1 test file. I executed code for 1st train file,then it works well. But when I try for 2nd train file,no of features are different than 1st so it gives error. How can I train my model if I have multiple such dataset files.